# How to use data from a callback function in the render method in a react class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to javascript and react and for my instance I need to use the data from a `xmlHttpRequest` inside the `render` function of a class that extends `react.component`

I have used a `window.localstorage` to save the result and use it in other places. But that doesn't look like the way to do it properly.

What I need:

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  MyFunction() {             //the function that includes a callback function

    setInterval(function() { //the callback function

                //get some data

    }, 1000)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now how can I use this data in render?

Answer (score 0):

Take whatever response you get in your callback, which you earlier used to save to `localstorage`, and set it to state.

```
const response = res
this.setState({response})
```

Then refer the same in your render

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>{this.state.response}</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. already have tried that. and it works. My concern is that is it the best way to do it? Is there no eventual crashing dangers or security threats?

Comment: security implications depend on whether the callback is something you control or not. You can parse the response and check it if necessary.

Comment: Your concern is really vague, can you help us understand what kind of data are you dealing with? React.js is a front end framework that relies on state to communicate information with other components, by design.

Comment: Furthermore, your question in no way indicated you had security concerns, please update the same with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use state in your class

```
class MyClass extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
        data:[]
        }
    }
    MyFunction() {   
       fetch("url").then(res => res.json()).then(data => this.setState({data}))
       .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {this.state.data}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great example of where to use [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

```
myFunction() {
  setInterval(function() {
    let newCount = this.state.count + 1
    this.setState({count: newCount})
  }, 1000)
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      Count is {this.state.count}
    </div>
  )
}
```

You'll need to call myFunction either as part of your `constructor` or in `componentDidMount` and you should set an initial state

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    count: 0
  }
  this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this)
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.myFunction()
}
```

NB: Depending on your compiler you might need some bindings in your function:

```
setInterval(function() {
  ...
}.bind(this), 1000)
```

...or your could use fat arrow notation, which binds implicitly:

```
setInterval(() => {
  ...
}, 1000)
```